# How to resolve types according to usages?

Tags: typescript

There is a type with unfixed set of keys which can be initializaed everywhere across the my app.
Is it possible to make return types resolved correctly in following case:

```
obj.setSmth('key1', 123)
obj.setSmth('key2', true)
obj.setSmth('another key', () => void)
```

Getters should be resolved to:

```
obj.getSmth('key1') // -> number
obj.getSmth('key2') // -> boolean
obj.getSmth('another key') // -> () => void
```

Last version of TS.

Plugin for TSC? Transformers? Some other workarounds?

Comment: When you create `obj` do you know what keys will be present in it ? Will there be multiple  instances of this object ?

Comment: 1) No, keys aren't known in advance. 2) There is only one instance for the entire application.

Comment: This can work:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgD0a4E0IFc4DGAhgHZwAmAlgM4xSUBGuMwcMAFsNa+cAQDZEoRGJQglqcSmW4A3YMP5wAZpX5cUvAUNYBzfhAZElCFHHNSSLKMqIFWAcQNH+AYXEsQMAPIMAVnzwphYhcADWwACeAIwAXHAkuAC2DAoA3GYWqKhaglB6zsaImebS1rb2cE6Gxu5WoD7+gcWhFgDkpBAcCuFRbfFwABQAlHAAvAB8cLIQlOQZIdkoMJFgjoX8BHWe8GMtFtwwAMpJHAA8ANJwDcAk5JIRkRDKVRvbDb4BBDATg2HxFwANNNjLhgPFqi53l5PoEANoXAC6w3iMzmcBKcF0wGOp3Yl2uXlu916TxekNqHg+TW+v3+cAuKNeNTcVJhNJgCMRKFQKHU8EMfghGy2bN2CVw-H4AEIMihBQA6Q4nDiDNqPaJtYHRABMAGZhvL-EqcSr2GrOt0oKStUNRpNEHAkIajX4Fdjcar1VFNaMMHAALRTRIpBSu92mvEWkhdTjWx5tP2YIN28ZTNHkIA

Comment: [lol](https://tsplay.dev/w8LL9w)

Comment: @kelly wow! it looks awesome. just one point isn't clear - why it will not work if I put a getter call into the function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmMC8MDeBfA3AWAChCAzAVzGCgEtw4koAeAFQBoYBpGJADyiTAAmEOFARUwAczYA1AHwAKeMgBcMVjADWSAJ6r2bAG4BDADakkq6QEpVRiBCQIowpSirCmMAGSYYAbQB9GHEOAF1LGCxMQhhYmAB6eIABZwBaKgkwRCQYuNc-LW1QtBhjMyR8AixCEnJKGjAYCXpmNk4ePkFhQpBiNQVXVXVCvRs1P3ZijFzY5ChSBEb8wtDK6qICByhFKGy2ACIARgAmAGZ9tgAWAFYANitK2opqWj5oQ5h5K2iCOKb6HZ7GBHM77B4JeIwMCkAC2ACNHIQojUCEA

Comment: `store` is not guaranteed to be filled with values in that context. The function can be called at any time, and so TypeScript replaces the context with a new one. Notice that when you call `set` in the function it works.

Comment: Sadly. So it won't solve my problem. Maybe look towards using Proxy or reflect-metadata